# Cookie code failing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cookies

I use this code in my website skin. This work currently in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. I use `cookie.js` framework to save css file name in cookie.

```
//create  and set cookies for colors
var skinFileName = Cookies.get('skin_file').toString();
//if don't exist cookie for style Load Default stlye
if (skinFileName=="") {
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/style.css');
} else {
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + skinFileName + '.css');
}

//change colors of skin
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.on('click', function () {
  var dataTem = $(this).data('theme');
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
  Cookies.set('skin_file', dataTem.toString(), { expires: 60, path: '' });
});
```

When I execute this code

```
$('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/pink.css');)
```

in console worked but when I execute this code

```
var skinFileName = Cookies.get('skin_file').toString();
```

I get this error : `TypeError: Cookies.get(...) is undefined`

Comment: which part is not working , are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: is cookies enabled in ff? I check it .cookie is enable in ff for all sites.I update my question

Comment: have you included Cookie.js ?

Comment: Normally cookies in jQuery using Cathcart, has the syntax $.cookie

Comment: user2181397 : Yes I used

Comment: mplungjan : If your mean is  has the syntax $.cookie in cookis.js ? No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the issue is with `Cookies.get('skin_file').toString();` .When you run it first time it wont get the cookie and if you call `toString` on it it will throw an `undefined...` .So you can try by removing the `toString();`

Here is a sample fiddle which I tried . I have changed the id of element but the objective is same

```
//create  and set cookies for colors
var skinFileName = Cookies.get('skin_file');
//if don't exist cookie for style Load Default stlye
if (skinFileName=="") {
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/style.css');
} else {
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/skinFileName.css');
}

//change colors of skin
var colors = $('#color_skin');
colors.on('click', function () {
  //var dataTem = $(this).data('theme');
  $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/dataTem.css');
  Cookies.set('skin_file', dataTem.toString(), { expires: 60, path: '' });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/q8ngfu70/)

Hope this will be useful

Comment: user2181397 Thank you .It solved .The tostring() function don't defined for firefox